# Sorting Rows in Excel with POI

Tags: apache-poi

I'm trying to sort an XSSF sheet in POI and I'm not having any luck. I found a prior post saying the issue with shifting rows was fixed in 3.9 but I'm still getting an error. I tried using the method below and this is the error I'm getting..

```
   /**
 * Sorts (A-Z) rows by String column
 * @param sheet - sheet to sort
 * @param column - String column to sort by
 * @param rowStart - sorting from this row down
 */
private void sortSheet(Sheet sheet, int column, int rowStart) {
    boolean sorting = true;
    int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    while (sorting == true) {
        sorting = false;
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            // skip if this row is before first to sort
            if (row.getRowNum()<rowStart) continue;
            // end if this is last row
            if (lastRow==row.getRowNum()) break;
            Row row2 = sheet.getRow(row.getRowNum()+1);
            if (row2 == null) continue;
            String firstValue = (row.getCell(column) != null) ? row.getCell(column).getStringCellValue() : "";
            String secondValue = (row2.getCell(column) != null) ? row2.getCell(column).getStringCellValue() : "";
            //compare cell from current row and next row - and switch if secondValue should be before first
            if (secondValue.compareToIgnoreCase(firstValue)<0) {                    
                sheet.shiftRows(row2.getRowNum(), row2.getRowNum(), -1);
                sheet.shiftRows(row.getRowNum(), row.getRowNum(), 1);
                sorting = true;
            }

        }
    }


Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_orphaned(XmlObjectBase.java:1258)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTRowImpl.getR(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.getRowNum(XSSFRow.java:322)
    at Objects.Event.sortSheet(Event.java:426)
    at Objects.Event.writeRigSheetsAverages(Event.java:394)
    at Objects.GroupInfo.seperateRigTypes(GroupInfo.java:138)
    at Objects.GroupInfo.<init>(GroupInfo.java:46)
    at DowntimeReports.StartProgram(DowntimeReports.java:135)
    at DowntimeReports.<init>(DowntimeReports.java:52)
    at DowntimeGUI.actionPerformed(DowntimeGUI.java:89)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My sheet starts with 5 rows but when I make the shift it gets reset to 3.

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using?

Comment: I believe we have POI 3.11 available - https://poi.apache.org/download.html. Try using v3.11

Comment: I am using POI 3.12  still facing this issue. Any update on this ?

Comment: Posted a bug https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59733  and got confirmation from POI that its a bug